# custom template not working in django formtools

Tags: python, django, django-formwizard

I have been trying to add a multi page form in my Django application using the formtools wizard. I need to setup custom forms for each step. There are 2 steps in total. Here is the code that I have:

views.py

```
TEMPLATES = {"initial": "my_app/form_initial.html",
         "final": "my_app/form_last.html"}


class ModelCreateView(SessionWizardView):
    model = MyModel
    template_name = "my_app/model_form.html"
    file_storage =      
    FileSystemStorage(location=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'custom'))

    def get_template_names(self):
        return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]
```

my_app/model_form.html

```
{% extends "my_app/base.html" %}

{% block extra_css %}
{{ wizard.form.media }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    {{ wizard.management_form }}
    <h1>{{ wizard }}</h1>
    {% if wizard.form.forms %}
        <h1>{{ wizard.form.forms }}</h1>
        {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
        {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
            {{ form }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        {{ wizard.form }}
    {% endif %}
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

my_app/form_initial.html

```
 <-- custom form template for step 1 -->
```

my_app/form_last.html

```
 <-- custom form template for step 2 -->
```

if I understand it correctly, the custom form templates will replace the

```
{{ form }}
```

tag in the base template being called(my_app/model_form.html).

My problem here is that, with the current code, the  my_app/form_initial.html is being called directly.

Also if I try to just include

```
{{ wizard.management_form }}
```

in my_app/form_initial.html and enclose the necessary form elements, on submit, it just reloads the current page rather than taking me to my_app/form_last.html

Please let me know what am I doing wrong here.

**UPDATE**: I fixed the issue with custom template by properly extending the base form template. But now when I submit on the first step, the same step page reloads rather than going to the next step. Please let me know how do I debug this?

**UPDATE 2**: I tried debugging more and found this, my fields are not getting validated even though the post request contains the fields, the `form.is_valid()` returns false. The `form.errors` says that all the fields are `missing`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were 2 problems in the method that I had implemented the templates.

1. I had assumed that the custom step form templates would be substituted in their own once a base template is defined in the view. The correct method to do this is define the base template template and extend it in the custom step template.

eg:

base_form_template.html

```
{% block content %}
<form style="height:inherit;" action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    {{ wizard.management_form }}
    {{ wizard.form.errors}}
    {{ wizard.form.non_field_errors}}
    {% block custom_form %}
    {% endblock %}
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

step1.html

```
{% extends "my_app/base_form_template.html" %}

<-- custom form template code goes here -->
```

step2.html

```
{% extends "my_app/base_form_template.html" %}

<-- custom form template code goes here -->
```

2. In my custom form template, the `name` attribute of the input fields need to be set to `wizard.form.<model_attribute>.html_name`. This was difficult to find. I had initially just set it `wizard.form.<model_attribute>` and wondered why it didn't work. Did some more digging and found this. The `html_name` is different as its of the format `<step_name>_<field_name>`. Looking at it now it does make sense to have names like this.

Answer (score 0):

I got the wizard working in my app with an extra list of tuples to map the forms. Try this and see if it works.

```
WIZARD_FORMS = [("initial", InitailFormName),
                ("final" , FinalFormName),
            ]

TEMPLATES = {"initial": "my_app/form_initial.html",
             "final": "my_app/form_last.html"}


class ModelCreateView(SessionWizardView):
    model = MyModel
    template_name = "my_app/model_form.html"
    file_storage =      
    FileSystemStorage(location=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'custom'))

    def get_template_names(self):
        return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]
```

Comment: do you use the `WIZARD_FORMS` variable anywhere?

Comment: I am using the WIZARD_FORMS to name the forms being used (and optionally skipping one form). I also have a variable inside the wizard class: form_list = [WizardForm0a, WizardForm2, WizardForm3, WizardForm4, WizardForm5 ]. I can't remember exactly what I needed each section for, but it ended up working in the end.

Comment: I use such declaration in the urls file
`url(r'^my_app/create/$', MyModelCreateView.as_view([("initial", MyModelFormInitial),
         ("final", MyModelFormLast)]), name="model_create")`
but still it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Actually I do pass them in via urls.py, but declare them in the views.     url(r'^wizard/$',     GraduateDetailsWizard.as_view(WIZARD_FORMS, condition_dict=WIZARD_CONDITION_DICT),  name='graduate_wizard'),

Comment: strange..did that but couldn't make it work..
the template being called is just `my_app/form_initial.html`
also how did you pass the `WIZARD_FORMS` in the `urls.py` from `views.py`?

Comment: I import WIZARD_FORMS at the top of urls.py, then use it in the url that I showed above.

Comment: I figured out the problem. i wasn't properly extending the base form template in the custom form templates. Now the form loads as expected, but on submit the page just refreshes. It doesn't go to the next step. Any idea what can be the cause?

Comment: Its probably an error in the form data. Are you displaying the form errors?

Comment: I am filling 4 fields for a model from the first form and they are mentioned in the "Meta" for the `form` class. However, there are no errors displayed and the value for these fields are retrieved properly when checked in the `get_form` method. Is there any other way I can debug this?

Comment: I tried debugging more and found this, my fields are not getting validated
even though the post request contains the fields, the `form.is_valid()` returns false. The `form.errors` says that all the fields are `missing`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136908/discussion-between-keval-doshi-and-wobbily-col).

Answer (score 0):

What Keval said is correct - the main issue that caused `self.cleaned_data['field']` to be empty is that I needed to use `form.field.html_name` instead of `form.field.name` for the name field of the template.

However, this isn't all that clear from the documentation provided. Here's an excerpt from my template page, so it's even clearer:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>{{ form.account_name.label }}</label>
  <input name="{{ form.account_name.html_name }}"
         value="{{ form.account_name.value|default_if_none:'' }}"
         class="form-control">
</div>
```